# 's3cmd sync' is working but not 'aws s3 sync'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3cmd

I have an EC2 instance in which I want to download a file.
I could able to download using s3cmd command

```
    s3cmd sync s3://<Bucket>/filename /tmp
    100% downloaded
```

But, using the 'asw s3 sync' it is not working,

```
 aws s3 sync s3://<Bucket>/filename /tmp

 NO OUTPUT
```

Both do not work at a time?

Comment: how about this `aws s3 ls`, any output?

Comment: 'aws s3 ls' does listing all the buckets. But 'aws s3 sync' not working.

Comment: They are two different commands. Are you try to sync a "folder" or a specific object?

Comment: I am trying to sync a file into the rpm folder. That is an object.

aws s3 sync s3://<Bucket>/filename /tmp

Comment: If its a single object, just use cp. Sync is intended be used with directories. Its possible that the s3cmd (which is not supported by amazon) does support sync on both objects and directories.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I didn't have the right permissions for the folder that I was trying to copy to. The aws command didn't give me any errors though. I just paused for a while making it seem like the command was doing something and then completed with no output.